Encontrar valores diferentes con Pandas Python
Buen día
Estoy trabajando con pandas, pero el problema que tengo es que recibo unos informes pero estos vienen con información sucia o no llevan un orden al momento de hacer los registros.
Ejemplo: Tengo una columna que dice Moneda pero los registros siempre los ingresan de manera diferente ('USD,$USD,?USD$,usd) y asi de muchas maneras
Lo que actualmente estoy haciendo es tener una lista con todas las variantes de escribirlo
USD = {'US$', 'USD/m2', 'USD', 'USD$','US $','$US','US4','US5'}

MXN = {'MX', 'MX $', 'MX$', 'MXN', 'MXN/m2', 'MXP$', '_', 'mxn', 'pesos'
       ,'PESOS','Pesos','M.N. ','MN','MXP','mnx','MXNP'}
NA={'na','n.a','N.A.','n.a.',' ','-','_','TBD','Por Confirmar'}

y con un .replace es como estoy homologando los registros. Me gustaría saber si hay una manera más automatica de detectar las distintas maneras de escribir un registro, porque así como lo estoy haciendo cuando lo exporto a excel es cuando me doy cuenta si hay una nueva manera de escribirlo y tengo que agregarlo a la lista y nuevamente generar el archivo.
Muchas gracias

Hola German, en lugar de permitirles escribir la "Moneda", porque no mejor les das vos las opciones que pueden seleccionar. Así te vas a ahorrar todo estos problemas y de paso lo estandarizas. Mientras los usuarios puedan ingresar a mano este dato, nunca vas a poder dejar de revisar lo que escribieron.

Es que el problema es a mi me mandan los informes de distintas áreas, ya me lo mandan con la información completa. Y este patrón no solo se repite en la columna "Moneda " sino en varías columnas como "Ciudad" , "Estado", "Calle" y por eso me gustaría saber si hay una manera de encontrar todas esas discrepancias para poder homologar todas las maneras en que escriben esos registros

No se puede, con tan solo ver los casos que manejas actualmente está claro que no hay un patrón... el usuario es libre de escribir lo que se le ocurra y contra eso no vas a poder hacer nada. Así como hoy escribo "USD", mañana puedo poner "DOLAR", " USD ", "U$$D", "DOL$", lo que se le ocurra. El peor de los casos sería que pongan "$", que moneda es? Pesos? Dolares? Ni idea?

Y se podría comparar los valores que tengo en las listas con los valores de las columnas? Tal vez no cambiarlos directamente, pero saber cuales no están homologados o no están en la lista

Si, pero eso solo te sirve para detectar "una nueva moneda", no te evita tener que actualizar tu lista de equivalencias

Si, no pasaría nada
Sería mas fácil cuales no están y actualizar la lista antes de exportarlo a Excel
Sabrás la manera de hacerlo? Por favor

Continuemos el debate en el chat.

¿Por que no es del todo posible?
Como te han dicho en comentarios y en chat, no hay una manera completamente automatica de detectar todas las posibles palabras/variantes de palabras con las que se puede mencionar algo, tal como un tipo de moneda o una calle, ni siquiera con ia.
A la fecha de esta respuesta, a pesar de las capacidades de la ia, es una tecnología en pañales y puede darte muchos falsos positivos o falsos negativos. Además, se debería de actualizar su modelo para "ponerla al día" de los cambios en el lenguaje, lo que da la impresión de que llevaría a tu cliente y/o a vos a depender de actualizaciones constantes para que todo siga andando.
Algunas Ideas

Lo habitual es restringir las posibles palabras y formatos (tales como fechas) permitidas en el archivo.

Podés dejar ese peso al cliente, y, en el caso de la moneda, que envíe a tu programa una tabla con las posibles equivalencias y formatos. Pero esto podría ser molesto, aunque como contrapeso, esta molestia tal vez podría motivar al cliente a estandarizar el formato con el que se escribe el dato, para ahorrar trabajo.

Hacer una investigación profunda y armar la lista de equivalencias y/o formatos. Mismo problema que con ia.

Estandarizar la generación del excel creando una gui para el cliente.


La posible aplicación de estas ideas depende de la libertad y tiempo que tengas en cuanto a tu proyecto. Tengo entendido que la primera y la ultima no son posibles.
Reduciendo ambiguedades
Adicional a todo, se puede eliminar algunas de las ambiguedades innecesarias de la palabra. Una vez obtenido el texto que quiero "simplificar", suelo hacer lo siguiente (el orden importa, esta forma está orientada al español, por lo que puede no funcionar en otros lenguajes):

Eliminar espacios al principio y final del texto.
Convertir todo el texto a minusculas o mayusculas.
Quitar tildes.
Reducir grupos conformados por el mismo caracter a un solo caracter. Por ejemplo, ppperro  de juan se convertiría en pero de juan

Este proceso resulta en una especie de "id". Al aplicar este procedimiento, la id "esta maria", se podrá obtener a partir de variantes como " está María ", "eeesssta Maria", "EsTA MARia", etc. Lo que, en mi opinión, reduce mucho las posibles variantes. Por lo tanto, suponiendo que nuestra función se llame simplifique, significaría que simplifique(" está María ") == simplifique("eeesssta Maria") daría True.
Por supuesto, esto no cubre todas las ambiguedades posibles, por ejemplo, no cubre una letra faltante o una palabra desconocida para el programa.
Formato: El problema de "multiples formatos validos para el mismo texto"
Esto es importante a la hora de trabajar las ambiguedades en el texto recibido.
Hace un tiempo, respondí una pregunta donde mencionaba que si un texto tiene dos o más formatos validos, no hay manera de discernir cual es el correcto. Esto se puede ver con formatos de fecha como YYYY-MM-DD y YYYY-DD-MM, en los cuales la fecha "2020-10-12" es valida para ambos formatos, solo que en el primero el dia es 12 y en el segundo 10.
Este problema no se podrá resolver a menos que se especifique el formato de ese dato especificamente. De hecho, este problema tampoco puede ser resuelto por un ser humano si lo pensás.
